# Create jar file from single class file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Is there any possibility to create a jar file, not for the entire project, but only for one class file in IntelliJ? In that file, I don't need all libraries and etc. I need only files with a specific class.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and learn how to use jar at the command line. You can put as many class files as you want in a jar file

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html). It is very well explained.

Example of how to do this with `jar` commands:

```
jar cvf jar_name.jar YourClassNameComesHere.class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Create Directory` button in the `Output Layout` tree under `File | Project Structure | Artifacts` to create desired packages in the jar and then use `+ | File`:

[image]

To build the artifact please use `Build | Build Artifacts` from the main menu.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html for more information.